# scrollable feed reader in primefaces

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces

i want to show live news in my application for wihch i am using primefaces feed reader as follows:

```
    <div>

                <p:feedReader size="20" value="http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s=yhoo" var="feed">  
    <h:outputText value="#{feed.title}" style="font-weight: bold"/>  
    <br />  
    <h:outputText value="#{feed.description.value}" escape="false"/>  
    <p:separator />  
</p:feedReader>  
            </div>
```

but i wish to make this news scrollable. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing the `<p:feedReader` inside the `<p:scrollPanel>`

take a look at the showcase [PrimeFaces ScrollPanel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/scrollPanel.jsf)